# Error MSB4094: how can archieve my project?

Tags: android, archive

I get this error and I can't archieve my project...

**MSB4094: "obj\Release\90\testUC.Android.dll;obj\Release\90\testUC.Android.dll" is an invalid value for the "OutputAssembly" parameter of the "Csc" task. Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".
Done building project "testUC.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.**

it looks like that the first trial worked but then no more...

Any idea?

Comment: Well, i was having the MSB4094 when i'm trying to build my project, the solution for me was reverting some changes i saw made in Git Changes. I know its vague, that's why i put it here as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

### Try those steps:

1. Close your Visual Studio.
2. Remove .vs folder.
3. Relaunch and build